# Ionic2 Header Buttons Error

Tags: javascript, mobile, ionic2

This is a error of the header bar when I'm using Ionic 2, as opposed to those from the documentation. I don't know what's wrong with it. It's the most plain code from my starting point.

[image]

And another instance with plain ion-buttons...
[image]

Comment: please post your code in text as opposed to screenshots. Your template seems ok, which version of the beta are you using? have you edited the scss files? it looks related to your stylesheets

Comment: I did not change anything... Ionic2 is a fresh install in my system...

Comment: and some codes for the header are copy pasted from the official ionic2 docs...